# How to support right to left printing in mfc application

Tags: printing, mfc, right-to-left

I have a problem in printing right to left in my application. I use the codejock report control; it prints the left to right view very well and this is an example:

[image]

When the layout is rtl the control renders very well on the screen and also the print preview is fine, but printing results in a distorted document like the following:

[image]

I have tried to override the OnPrepareDC of the view and used the pDC->SetLayout(LAYOUT_RTL) but it failed, I need help on how to fix this.

Comment: Have you contacted CodeJock support, or, forums?  Seems like a common problem that they should be able to help with.

Comment: in the file XTPReportView.cpp they have a comment about not supporting rtl in print mode but in preview it is ok, I wanted to fix it or find any solution, this is the comment. if (pInfo->m_bPreview) //PRINT MODE in RTL does not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have found a solution for RTL printing issue.

the reason of the problem is that not all the printer's drivers support mirroring so calling the SetLayout(RTL) function on the printer's DC will not work in all printer's drivers.

The first step is not to call SetLayout(RTL) at all,
then you should override drawing methods in report paint manager class to set the alignment of each drawing rectangle when you are in RTL printing mode.

Comment: That really was the reason but I hope if codejock get informed with your solution and attach the files you edited so that the next release come with a fixed rtl print this will be so nice.

Comment: thanks for considering my answer, actually that's exactly what I did.
I told them about the solution and I wish they will consider it.

Comment: This is so helpful, to avoid conflict between new features in controls and your current answer, they will take it in mind in all next releases I hope so.

Comment: i am facing the same problem can you please post some sample code

Comment: @HuzifaTerkawi
unfortunately, there is no straight forward solution (code sample) for this problem, however, you should follow the following guidelines:
1 -  **never** call SetLayout(RTL) on the DC, so the alignment will always be left to right.

2 -  As a result you have to override drawing methods in multiple classes such as TCXTPReportRow::Draw to fix the alignment manually and iterate over the columns in reverse order.

Comment: this solution is based on the fact that you have the source code.
best regards